# Returns as value or as reference through parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, reference

```
std::vector<std::string> get() {
    std::vector<string> result {};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000) {
        result.emplace_back("test" + to_string(i));
    }

    return result;
}

//or
void get(std::vector<std::string>& result) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000) {
        result.emplace_back("test" + to_string(i));
    }
}
```

//Is it more efficient to go through the reference than to return it? Or is copying elision and is it the same in terms of efficiency?

```
int main()
{
    auto arr = get();
    std::vector<std::string> arrPassingByRef{};
    get(arrPassingByRef);
}
```

Comment: they have different semantics and thats what should drive the decision (one adds to a vector the other creates a new one). Worries about efficiency are for later when you have working code and can confirm that this function is a bottleneck

Comment: Since you've tagged it C++11, copy elision isn't mandatory (but allowed) and if you happen to have a compiler that _moves_ it out of the function, taking it _by-reference_  would probably be a little cheaper - but you'd then be micro optimizing for an old compiler.

Comment: Before C++11, no move semantic, and (N)RVO optional, so out-parameter for big object. Since C++11, move-semantic, and since C++17, guaranty RVO (NRVO still optional).

Comment: It looks like you're writing this in the form of a performance test. However, the overhead of creating/returning the vector is going to be trivial compared to the cost of adding strings to it (and indeed of creating those strings). I can't imagine this test resulting in a meaningful difference. That's probably a sign that you're worrying about the wrong thing.

Comment: for recent standard this is what the core guidlines suggest: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-conventional (expensive to move -> use a reference parameter)